# Why am I getting a syntax error on the first line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I copied this straight from my textbook and it still won't work. Thanks in advance.

```
Def main() :
    filename = input('Enter a filename:  ')
try:
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    contents = infile.read()
    print(contents)
    infile.close()

main()
```

Comment: Well, the try is not within the main function and Def is not capitalized

Comment: Are you certain you copied it correctly? I see several issues: no indentation, `def` is spelled with a capital `D` but should instead be all lowercase, no `except` or `finally` clauses to the `try:` block.

Comment: The [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) isn't all that long and gives you code you can copy and paste directly. Perhaps you want to give that a try first and learn the basics of the syntax?

Comment: Also, please use four spaces for code on Stackoverflow, not tabs

Comment: thanks ill try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why it is not working is because you wrote Def instead of def. Python is case sensitive like many other languages. Also, have you used indents with your code? Please add 4 lines to include this code in your main function.

```
def main() :
    filename = input('Enter a filename:  ')

    try:
        infile = open(filename, 'r')
        contents = infile.read()
        print(contents)
    infile.close()

main()
```

This would probably be the corrected version.

Comment: Shouldn't there also be an `except` after the `try`?

Comment: You can’t have `try` unless you also have a `except` or `finally`

Comment: Don't you mean four spaces, not four lines?

Comment: You should use `with open()` really

Answer (score 2):

Uncapitalize `def` and add 
4 spaces at the beginning of each line after a `:` 
except for that last `main()` that should be on the left.